# Javascript - Problema em função que adiciona textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, label

Na minha página em PHP e Javascript, criei um espaço que contém duas Textbox e uma label clicável pra adicionar mais Textbox, se necessário, ao div *numPart*:

```
<div id="numPart">
    <div class="inputMGM"><input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]"></input></div>
    <div class="inputMGM"><input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]"></input></div>
</div>

<label id="addPart" class="SpaceEnviar" style="cursor: pointer; decoration: underline">ADICIONAR PARTICIPANTE</label>
```

E a função que adiciona mais textbox é a seguinte.

```
var x=1;
$("#addPart").click(function(){
   var d = document.getElementById('numPart');
   d.innerHTML += "<div class='inputMGM'><input name='part' id='' class='validate[required]'></input></div>";
});
```

Contudo, se eu tiver preenchido alguma das Textbox existentes e clicar pra adicionar mais uma, o texto existente que eu preenchi some.

Como eu posso fazer pra manter os textos escritos nas Textbox existentes a medida que eu for clicando pra adicionar mais ao formulário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `innerHTML` substutui todo o conteúdo, para adicionar mais conteúdo no final utilize o `append`.

Agora dois pontos no código existente:

- Você está utilizando `javascript` e `jQuery` em um mesmo código, se usar jQuery, use o máximo que puder
- Não existe `<input></input>` a tag é fechada nela mesma - `<input type="text" />`.

Veja o exemplo com as melhorias apontadas.

```js
$("#addPart").on('click', function() {
  var html = "<div class='inputMGM'><input name='part' id='' class='validate[required]' /></div>";
  $('#numPart').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numPart">
  <div class="inputMGM">
    <input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]" />
  </div>
  <div class="inputMGM">
    <input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]" />
  </div>
</div>

<label id="addPart" class="SpaceEnviar" style="cursor: pointer; decoration: underline">ADICIONAR PARTICIPANTE</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso deves utilizar a função `.append` visto que cada vez que fazias o `+=`, para ele era como se estivesses a dar um html completamente novo.

```js
var x=1;
$("#addPart").click(function(){
   $("#numPart").append("<div class='inputMGM'><input name='part' id='' class='validate[required]'></input></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numPart">
    <div class="inputMGM"><input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]"></input></div>
    <div class="inputMGM"><input name="part" id="" class="validate[required]"></input></div>
</div>

<label id="addPart" class="SpaceEnviar" style="cursor: pointer; decoration: underline">ADICIONAR PARTICIPANTE</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Copiar sempre os conteudos do ultimo input:

```
$("#addPart").on('click', function() {
     var newField = $('.inputMGM').last().clone();
    $(this).before(newField)
});
```

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/996brwn4/1/)

Comment: Ótima ideia usar o `last()`. +1

Comment: Obrigado @PedroCamaraJunior